# Collisions in Authoritative Server for Socket IO game

Tags: node.js, socket.io, collision-detection, game-physics, phaser-framework

I am trying to make an io game using Phaser and NodeJS/Socket.io. I realized to prevent cheating I need to make an authoritative server that runs the game.

While trying to architect the server, I wasn't sure what to do for collisions. Right now my idea is to divide the canvas into tiles and check each tile for collisions but that still seems like alot of work for each update. On the flip side I could loop through all attack sprites and look for overlaps with specific tiles, and then check the sprites in those tiles. I am afraid this is too slow, but I might be wrong. Does anyone have any better ideas?

And does anyone have any recommendations for server side physics engines so that maybe I don't have to do the math for collisions and movement?

Comment: The last part of your question about recommendations for server side physics engines is off-topic here.  From the help center: **Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.**.

Answer (score 2):

Good thinking. The best way to do it afaik is to use a method called binary space partitioning, where you split your world up into chunks, then check for collision of objects only within those chunks. If you have an object on one side of your world, for instance, you will not need to check for a collision between that object and another object on the other side of your world in a different chunk.

If you haven't done it before, you might not want to write your own physics engine since there are so many options available. Even Bullet3D has a web port known as Ammojs. Iirc there is a version that works with node, but you'll have to do some work with multithreading or replace the webworkers to get it working right.

Here is a blog post by someone else who got a socket and node game up and running with Box2d as the physics engine:

http://paal.org/blog/2012/07/06/running-box2d-on-server-with-node-js-via-socket-io/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ty6wA2wSX4

Keep in mind, even if you're running it on an authoritative server at say, 60fps, at some point you might want to run it on the client as well, especially if the client is updating between renders from the server. You MIGHT have to write some prediction or interpolation code so that the animations don't look super janky.

Hope this helped.